# Including javax persistence in a Cordova/Android project

Tags: java, android, cordova, gradle, objectbox

I am trying to incorporate [ObjectBox](https://objectbox.io) in my hybrid Cordova/Android project. By dint of some trial and error I have managed to figure out two of the steps involved.

- The app level `build.gradle` file has to be modified to include the ObjectBox Gradle plugin `classpath "io.objectbox:objectbox-gradle-plugin:2.5.0"`
- Define a `build-extras.gradle` file to "apply" the ObjectBox plugin  `ext.postBuildExtras = {apply plugin: 'io.objectbox'}`

The next step according to the [ObjectBox docs](https://docs.objectbox.io/getting-started) is to define at least one Entity class

However, the issue here is that I need to import the javax.persistence.* classes into the project.  It is not clear to me how I do this.  I have run into suggestions along the lines of including

```
compile group: 'javax.persistence', name: 'javax.persistence-api', version: '2.2'
```

in the dependencies section of the app level build.gradle file.  However, this causes gradle to complain that it does not know the `compile()` function. I'd be much obliged to anyone who might be able to tell me how this should be done.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of anyone running into this thread - you can download the JAR file for javax.persistence [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api/2.2).  Place this line in the folder `src/android/libs`of your custom plugin and then modify `plugin.xml`with the line

```
<lib-file src='src/android/libs/name-of-javax-persistence.jar'/>
```